# Why method wait() works without notify()?

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection, wait, notify

### Great thanks in advance!

I had problems with synchronizing 2 threads: main and thread which is called from **StepRunner.java**. I just need this that result of the iteration is displayed before a start of the next iteration.

**What I want:**

```
Please enter step number [1, 2, 3 or 4] or 5 for exit: 2
Please enter natural value for factorial computing: 2
2! = 2
Please enter step number [1, 2, 3 or 4] or 5 for exit:
```

**What I don't want:**

```
Please enter step number [1, 2, 3 or 4] or 5 for exit: 2
Please enter natural value for factorial computing: 2
Please enter step number [1, 2, 3 or 4] or 5 for exit: 2! = 2
```

For it I have synchronized block in **StepRunner.java**:

```
public void run() {
        thread.start();
        synchronized (thread) {
            try {
                while (thread.isAlive()) { /**Loop is an Oracle's recommendation*/
                    thread.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But why method wait() works correctly without method notify() in any place of my code?

Comment: Did you check that the loop is executed at all? It's just a guess but maybe the thread  holds its own monitor (or maybe the scheduler does) and thus the synchronized block only executes after the thread has finished and isn't alive any more.

Comment: When a thread dies it notifies itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Thread`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) states that `Thread.notifyAll()` is called internally when thread finishes:

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

As you can see, it's not recommended to use this feature, your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
thread.start();
try {
    thread.join();    
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Given the fact that this statement only appeared in Java 7 javadoc and it's recommended not to use this functionality, it looks like this behavior used to be an implementation detail of `Thread` class, but people began to rely on it, so that language authors had to document it.